# I want to automatically delete comments when building with webpack

Tags: webpack

**I want to automatically delete comments when building with webpack.**

・ I want to delete comments after //

・Can I delete comments by setting some options?

・how can I do?

---

▼main.js

```
// src/main.js　I want to delete this part
var m = require("mithril")

var UserList = require("./views/UserList")

m.mount(document.body, UserList)
//I want to delete this part.I want to delete this part.I want to delete this part.I want to delete this part.I want to delete this part.I want to delete this part.I want to delete this part.I want to delete this part.I want to delete this part.I want to delete this part.I want to delete this part.I want to delete this part.I want to delete this part.I want to delete this part.I want to delete this part.I want to delete this part.I want to delete this part.I want to delete this part.I want to delete this part.I want to delete this part.I want to delete this part.I want to delete this part.
```

---

▼package.json

```
 "scripts": {
     "build": "webpack src/index.js bin/main.js -p"
 }
```

---

```
$ npm start
```

Comment: You'll want to be using a minifier in production, which'll do this automatically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To customize Webpack default's configuration, you will need to create a specific file with the options you want.

To strip the comments, you will have to pass `comments: false` in the UglifyJs plugin.

```
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  // ...

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      comments: false
    }),
  ]
}
```

You can then write the configuration to `webpack.prod.js` and run webpack with the production environment `webpack --env=prod`.

Please read the [official documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production-build/#simple-approach) for more information.

Comment: After creating and placing webpack.prod.js, it worked as expected. Thanks!

Comment: is there a way without ejecting the app ?